# Arithmetic Operation Resulted in An Overflow ASP.net 2.0 VB

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I am working with the following code:

```
If chkApproximately.Checked Then
'.Item_Title = "~ " & String.Format("{0:N0}", Int32.Parse(Me.txtQuantity.Text)) & " " & IIf(Me.ddlUnits.Text = "Piece(s)", "", Me.ddlUnits.Text & " of ") & Me.ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text.Replace("-", "").Trim  'txtItem_Title.Text.Trim
.Item_Title = "~ " & String.Format("{0:N0}", Me.txtQuantity.Text) & " " & IIf(Me.ddlUnits.Text = "Piece(s)", "", Me.ddlUnits.Text & " of ") & Me.ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text.Replace("-", "").Trim  'txtItem_Title.Text.Trim
Else
.Item_Title = String.Format("{0:N0}", Me.txtQuantity.Text) & " " & IIf(Me.ddlUnits.Text = "Piece(s)", "", Me.ddlUnits.Text & " of ") & Me.ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text.Replace("-", "").Trim 'txtItem_Title.Text.Trim
End If
```

When I run the aspx page on the web server, provide values and submit the form, I receive the error message stated in the question header.  Can someone explain why this is happening and provide some suggested solutions?

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing.. try '+' instead of '&'

Comment: and do a CStr if you got a integer value. Also it occurred to tell you to check if the Int32.Parse has proper integer text and not empty string.

Comment: I commented out the first line as we don't want to do the int32.parse.  TxtQuantity is set to long in the library.  Thus, I commented out the original code and copied it, removing the int32.parse.  Anything else I should do?  Thanks much!!

Comment: I replaced all the & with + and the error still persists.  Any thing else I should check?